# Enable query based wordpress search ?s=<query>

Tags: search

I want the search results to be shown on `/search/?s=foo` (where I search for `foo`)

But it's currently showing on `/search/foo` and I have no idea why.

**Context**

Running WP `v4.8.2` with a custom theme I wrote.

My permalink settings are: `/%postname%/`

Comment: so what is the actual question? and `/search` is not a core wordpress url AFAIK so where do you get it from?

Comment: @MarkKaplun search results are showing `at /search/<query>`  not `/search/?s=<query>` - how do I make it show as the latter.

Comment: @MarkKaplun the search results show based on the `search.php` template

Comment: no, the search url is something that is either added by you or by a plugin. both your comments still do not explain what is the question.... please edit the question to make it explicit that you are interested in the url structure and not in some kind of integration with GA

Comment: @MarkKaplun I've updated the question in an attempt to be more clear

Comment: FWIW, I have tried to use a `/search` url on local install and got a 404 page. There is something in your theme/plugins doing that.disable plugins, switch to core theme and make sure you use the default htaccess. Than start enabling thing untill you find out who to blame